# Mock api call to fail a certain number of times with jest and axios

Tags: javascript, api, mocking, jestjs, axios

I have a function that sets up an api call and then passes this function to a retry function which executes the call and retries the call, up to 5 times, if it fails.

```
public someAPICall() {
        const promiseFunction = () => axios.post('/some/path/', {
            headers: {
                //some headers in here
            },
        });
        return executePromise(promiseFunction, 5);
}

private async executePromise(promiseFunction, numberOfTimesToTryAgain) {
    try {
        // execute api call
        return await promiseFunction();
    }
    catch (error) {
        if (retries > 0) {
            // try api call again if it has failed less than 5 times
            return executePromise(promiseFunction, --numberOfTimesToTryAgain);
        }
        return error;
    }
}
```

I'd like to test `someAPICall` and mock the results of the axios call to fail a certain amount of times using jest.
I can mock the axios.post call in my test file doing this:

```
jest.mock('axios');
mockPost = jest.fn(() => {});
(<jest.Mock>axios.create) = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    post: mockPost
  };
});
```

But how can I make it so the post call fails, for example, 3 times and then succeeds?

Comment: You can pass to mock function boolean argument `success` for example

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
 mockPostFailTwice = jest.fn()
.mockImplementation(() => {
  return 200;
})
.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  throw 500;
})
.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  throw 500;
});
```

This causes the post execution to throw a 500 error the first 2 times and return a 200 on the third.